# why this script (pinescript) not exiting when the candle color changed?

Tags: pine-script

I want to exit LONG when the candle closed RED , exit SHORT when the candle closed GREEN.

Also want to exit if certain % profit achived.

below code is opening LONG and closing... similar for SHORT.

```
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price / (1+shortProfitPerc)

closedGreen = barstate.isconfirmed and (close > open)
closedRed = barstate.isconfirmed and (close < open)

if (inDateRange)
    if(enterLONG and strategy.position_size == 0 )
        strategy.entry(id="LONG" , long=true , when=highABO)
    if (enterSHORT and strategy.position_size == 0 )
        strategy.entry(id="SHORT" , long=false , when=lowABO)



positions = strategy.position_size



if (strategy.position_size > 0  )
    strategy.exit("Exit/TP","LONG" , limit = longExitPrice)
    if(closedRed)
        strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","SHORT")    

if (strategy.position_size < 0  and close > open)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","SHORT" , limit = shortExitPrice)
    if(closedGreen)
        strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","SHORT" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `strategy.exit()` without parameters. Use `strategy.close()` instead.

```
if(closedRed)
    strategy.close("Short")
```